# Advanced Sublime Text 2 build systems

Tags: c, build, sublimetext2

Is there anyway to have Sublime Text 2 build all files in a project? I have a project that just has a few very simple C files in it, but by default, Sublime can only build one file at a time. The default C++ build rule is good at single file compiles, but that's about it.

I know its build system is mostly designed around simply calling another build system, such as `make`, but I'd love if I didn't have to deal with makefiles. I'd prefer if I could just have Sublime Text iterate over every file in my project and build them all with one rule. Is that at all possible?

Comment: You could possibly make an extension in Python, that iterates over the files in the current project. It will probably be much more work than to create a simple makefile though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makefiles are definitely one of the better options here, but if you'd rather not, you could just make a new build system that does something similar.

To get you started, Go to **Tools**->**Build System**->**New Build System...**, and add the following:

```
{
"cmd": ["g++", "*.cpp", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++"
}
```

Then save it in the default directory (`Packages/User/`)

This is a direct clone of the standard C++ build system, I've just modified the "single file" input argument to "all .cpp files in the current directory".

Hope that's a useful starting point!